# Where do the terms microcanonical, canonical and grand canonical (ensemble) come from?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology, history

Where do the terms [microcanonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcanonical_ensemble), [canonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_ensemble) and [grand canonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_canonical_ensemble) (ensemble) come from?

When were they coined and by whom? Is there any reason for the names or are they historical accidents?

Comment: I think it was J. W. Gibbs who first defined them, and probably coined the terms...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but I think they are introduced by [Gibbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah_Willard_Gibbs), and [that book](http://archive.org/details/elementaryprinci00gibbrich) (available for download) is of historic importance.

The word ensemble really just means "set" [in French](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble), you consider the space of [canonical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_coordinates) of the detailed mechanics = [microstates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstate_%28statistical_mechanics%29) and you impose statistics by the [fundamental postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_postulate_of_statistical_mechanics#Fundamental_postulate).

Comment: I was trying to read something in that book, but through Google in a reprint... so the right pages were not available. This is what it says in p. xi: "We consider especially ensembles 
of systems in which the index (or logarithm) of probability of 
phase is a linear function of the energy. This distribution, 
on account of its unique importance in the theory of statistical equilibrium, I have ventured to call _canonical_, and the 
divisor of the energy, the _modulus_ of distribution."

Comment: @Jellby: Well good :)

Comment: The book definitely looks like the first time canonical and microcanonical ensembles are called by those names. Grand canonical is missing, though.

Comment: Maybe in his "[Equilibrium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Equilibrium_of_Heterogeneous_Substances)" paper?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty In Gibbs' book the Grand canonical ensemble is simply called Grand ensemble and Gibbs also introduces the Petit ensemble as well with the Grand ensemble. They are both introduced in the last chapter of the book that treats systems with a varying amount of matter.

Answer (score -1):

I do not know where they come from, but in french a canonical form is an expression which appears "naturally". For instance the canonical basis for the linear space spanned by the second degree polynomial is made of: $\{1,X,X^2\}$